# I want to get the last line on the array

Tags: java

I have listed the last modified files in a folder and want to get the last line in the list.

Here is the program I have tried. Kindly help me to get the last line.

```
File dir = new File(path);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("R_*.tar.Z");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_COMPARATOR);

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(files[i]);
}

if (files() == 1) {
  System.out.println(list.get(files() - 1));
} else {
  System.out.println("List is empty or bigger than one");
}
```

Comment: You know how many items are in files (in the for loop).  You know how to get a given item number out of the array (in the println statement).  You can combine this knowledge to figure out how to get the item number corresponding to the number of items in files (remember to subtract one as Java starts counting at zero, not one)

Answer (score 2):

An [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) with n entries (n > 0) is indexed from 0 to n - 1, so how about

```
int n = files.length;
if (n > 0) {
  System.out.println(files[n - 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since array elements are indexed starting from 0, the last entry has index equal to *length of the array*-1.
So I would do it like this:

```
File lastEntry=files[files.length-1];
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: how possible to assign the value in lastEntry can be assigned to a String.        i try ...                                                                                                                  for(String i : lastEntry){
System.out.println(i);   its not working .. could you please help

Comment: If you mean the filename, then use the method getName()

Comment: it worked, thanks String ENV2 = lastEntry.getName();